# Lint found fatal errors

Tags: android

While generating release in android studio Build--> Generating signed Bundle/APK(s), I got below message
"Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target", because of this I am unable to generate the release build

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lintOptions { 

    checkReleaseBuilds false

}
```

to app level build.grade file within the android{ } section.

Comment: turning off the lint warning and errors is not the solution.

Comment: solving the linting error is always an option :)

Comment: In the new AS version 4.1.3, you won't be able to generate apk if you have fatal lint error.

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2022, the path to lint output might be changed. please check in For me I found the error mentioned in this path
`app\build\intermediates\lint_vital_intermediate_text_report\release\lint-results-release.txt`

a work around but will not solve the real problem and you might face troubles in production is to change below true to false. but I don't recommend it.

```
android {
lintOptions {
checkReleaseBuilds true          
            abortOnError true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In your Android Studio, switch to the Project pane. Go app --> build
> --> reports --> lint-results-prodRelease-fatal.xml

[image]

Here android studio will open the file explaining the error, message, and the place and line number where it has occurred.